# Faster way for scraping over 100,000 web pages in Python than Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, css, multithreading, selenium

I have over 100,000 web pages to scrape data from. The pages do not seem to have any dynamic data we need to wait to load (or that I need) so I am assuming there is no need to execute Javascript. I am currently using Selenium to do the job for me but it is currently using the Chrome Driver to do the scraping:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images":2}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

I have attempted to use the PhantomJS driver under the logic that Headless approach would be faster but it seems to be running much slower (an extra 2 seconds per page to load compared to the Chrome Driver):

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['javascriptEnabled'] = False
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--load-images=no'])
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
```

Am I missing something obvious with regards to the PHantomJS driver? My approach for scraping the data uses a mixture of CSS selectors and finding elements by ID and name to scrape the data I need.  Also, it would be in my best interest to do a multi-threaded approach here as well to cut back on waiting for this to finish. Selenium does not seem to do multi-threading well from what I understand. Does another module allow for this?

Comment: If there is no dynamic content use requests and lxml, it will be considerably faster

Comment: Selenium is really not appropriate for offline scraping. If your assumptions are indeed correct, a basic HTTP library will be vastly quicker, more concurrent, and less resource-intensive.